# How can I test chained promises in a Jest test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Below I have a test for my *login* actions. I'm mocking a Firebase function and want to test if the *signIn*/*signOut* functions are called.

The tests pass. However, I do not see my second console log. Which is this line `console.log('store ==>', store);`.

```
it('signIn should call firebase', () => {
  const user = {
    email: 'first.last@yum.com',
    password: 'abd123'
  };

  console.log('111');
  return store.dispatch(signIn(user.email, user.password)).then(() => {
    console.log('222'); // Does not reach
    expect(mockFirebaseService).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  console.log('333');
});
```

> ● login actions › signIn should call Firebase

> TypeError: auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

[image]

### Action being tested

```
// Sign in action
export const signIn = (email, password, redirectUrl = ROUTEPATH_DEFAULT_PAGE) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_PENDING });

  return firebase
    .then(auth => auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password))
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error('actions/Login/signIn', e);
      // Register a new user
      if (e.code === LOGIN_USER_NOT_FOUND) {
        dispatch(push(ROUTEPATH_FORBIDDEN));
        dispatch(toggleNotification(true, e.message, 'error'));
      } else {
        dispatch(displayError(true, e.message));
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch(displayError(false, ''));
        }, 5000);
        throw e;
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.getIdToken())
    .then((idToken) => {
      if (!idToken) {
        dispatch(displayError(true, 'Sorry, there was an issue with getting your token.'));
      }

      dispatch(onCheckAuth(email));
      dispatch(push(redirectUrl));
    });
};
```

### Full Test

```
    import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// Login Actions
import {
  // onCheckAuth,
  signIn,
  signOut
} from 'actions';

import {
  // USER_ON_LOGGED_IN,
  USER_ON_LOGGED_OUT
} from 'actionTypes';

// String Constants
// import { LOGIN_USER_NOT_FOUND } from 'copy';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

// Mock all the exports in the module.
function mockFirebaseService() {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(true));
}

// Since "services/firebase" is a dependency on this file that we are testing,
// we need to mock the child dependency.
jest.mock('services/firebase', () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(true)));

describe('login actions', () => {
  let store;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({});
  });

  it('signIn should call firebase', () => {
    const user = {
      email: 'first.last@yum.com',
      password: 'abd123'
    };

    console.log('111');
    return store.dispatch(signIn(user.email, user.password)).then(() => {
      console.log('222'); // does not reach
      expect(mockFirebaseService).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
    console.log('333');
  });

  it('signOut should call firebase', () => {
    console.log('signOut should call firebasew');
    store.dispatch(signOut()).then(() => {
      expect(mockFirebaseService).toHaveBeenCalled();
      console.log('store ==>', store);
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual({
        type: USER_ON_LOGGED_OUT
      });
    });
    console.log('END');
  });
});
```

Comment: You use `jest.mock('services/firebase', () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(true)))` to mock firebase in your signIn thunk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two issues here,

> The tests pass however I do not see my 2nd console log. Which is this
> line console.log('store ==>', store);.

That is because the test is not waiting for the promise to fulfill, so you should return it:

```
it('signOut should call firebase', () => {
    console.log('signOut should call firebasew');
    return store.dispatch(signOut()).then(() => { // NOTE we return the promise
      expect(mockFirebaseService).toHaveBeenCalled();
      console.log('store ==>', store);
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual({
        type: USER_ON_LOGGED_OUT
      });
      console.log('END');
    });

  });
```

You can find examples in the [Redux official documentation](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html).

Secondly, your signIn test is failing because you have mocked the wrong `firebase`:

```
jest.mock('services/firebase', () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(true)));
```

That should probably look more like:

```
jest.mock('services/firebase', () => new Promise(resolve => resolve({
    signInWithEmailAndPassword: () => { return { getIdToken: () => '123'; } }
})));
```

Comment: Ah thanks that was it! Yeah needed to put the actual function that was being resolved in that mock. Tests are now passing! I do get the catch err log `err => TypeError: res.getIdToken is not a function` however that is a new question. Will work on this more now thanks! 24 hours!

Comment: Posted a new question, the catch is returning an error and I can't seem to mock the res.getTokenId correctly. Mind a look for more points? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508225/how-to-fix-typeerror-is-not-a-function-testing-promises-with-jest

Answer (score 1):

> Login actions › signIn should call firebase
>
> TypeError: auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

This tells that your `store.dispatch(signIn(user.email, user.password))` fails, thus your second console.log won't go into your `then` chain, use `catch` or second callback argument of `then` instead.

Comment: Thanks! +1 that catch helps me spit out the error in the console.log instead of the test.